# Porque este metodo não esta somando?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

Estou tentando somar dois números pelo `Swing` e `JOptionPane`, mas está aparecendo o erro abaixo.

Alguém para me ajudar como resolver isso ?

> ```
> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: JOptionPane: parentComponent does not have a valid parent
>     at javax.swing.JOptionPane.createInternalFrame(JOptionPane.java:1510)
>     at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInternalOptionDialog(JOptionPane.java:1286)
>     at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInternalMessageDialog(JOptionPane.java:1099)
>     at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInternalMessageDialog(JOptionPane.java:1073)
>     at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInternalMessageDialog(JOptionPane.java:1047)
>     at DAO.Soma.somarNumeros(Soma.java:15)  at GUI.TesteMiniFrame.B_SomarActionPerformed(TesteMiniFrame.java:119)
>     at GUI.TesteMiniFrame.access$000(TesteMiniFrame.java:6)
>     at GUI.TesteMiniFrame$1.actionPerformed(TesteMiniFrame.java:33)
>     at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
>     at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
>     at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>     at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>     at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
>     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
>     at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
>     at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
>     at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
>     at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
>     at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
>     at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)  at
> ```

Segue a classe `Soma`

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Soma {
    public int somarNumeros(int numero1,int numero2){
        int resultado = numero1 + numero2;
        JOptionPane.showInternalMessageDialog(null, resultado);
        return 0; 
    } 
}
```

Segue a classe `TesteJInternalFrame`

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class TesteJInternalFrame extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {

    Soma somar;    

    public TesteJInternalFrame(){
        initComponents();
        somar = new Soma();
    }

    private void B_SomarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        int num1,num2,res;
        num1 = Integer.parseInt(TF_Valor1.getText());
        num2 = Integer.parseInt(TF_Valor2.getText()); 
        res = Integer.parseInt(TF_Resultado.getText());  
        TF_Resultado.setText(String.valueOf(res));  
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, somar.somarNumeros(num1,num2)); 
        //B_Somar.setText(String.valueOf());   
        //JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,s);  

    }                                       

    private void TF_Valor1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                         

    private void TF_Valor2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                         


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton B_Somar;
    private javax.swing.JTextField TF_Resultado;
    private javax.swing.JTextField TF_Valor1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField TF_Valor2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Parece que outros problemas, tipo um showDialog chamando outro dentre de si! estranho.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic na verdade são chamadas independentes(apesar de não ver com bons olhos ficar enchendo código de joptionpane), quando o método executar, surgirá o primeiro, depois que retornar, surgirá o segundo, sintaticamente não vai ocorrer erros, mas tambem acho estranho essa abordagem.

Comment: @diegofm, então, é nesse sentido mesmo. Acredito que isso é um má implementação e cause muitos problemas.

Comment: Obrigado! agora deixei apenas o JOptionPane da classe Soma. vlw

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A chamada `JOptionPane.showInternalMessageDialog();` foi feita para ser usada quando você possui um `JDesktopPane` ou `JInternalFrame`, e no seu caso, não está sendo chamado de nenhum frame interno, apenas está passando `null`.

Substitua por `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, resultado);` que resolverá o erro.

---

Analisando melhor seu código, pude ver que existe a possibilidade de utilizar o `showInternalMessageDialog()`, uma vez que sua classe principal herda de `JInternalFrame`. Apesar do método já sugerido acima funcionar, pelo fato de `JOptionPane` ser uma janela modal, ele trava o acesso as outras janelas até que seja fechado, e se o alerta for apenas para os Frames internos, este comportamento pode não ser o desejável.

Como alternativa ao método acima, sugiro que você altere sua classe `Soma` conforme abaixo:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Soma {
    public int somarNumeros(int numero1,int numero2){
        int resultado = numero1 + numero2;
        JOptionPane.showInternalMessageDialog(this, resultado);
        return resultado; 
    } 
}
```

E depois, apenas altere a linha onde você exibe o resultado, dentro do JInternalFrame, no método `B_SomarActionPerformed`. Ficaria assim:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class TesteJInternalFrame extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {

    Soma somar;    

    public TesteJInternalFrame(){
        initComponents();
        somar = new Soma();
    }

    private void B_SomarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        int num1,num2,res;
        num1 = Integer.parseInt(TF_Valor1.getText());
        num2 = Integer.parseInt(TF_Valor2.getText()); 
        res = Integer.parseInt(TF_Resultado.getText());  
        TF_Resultado.setText(String.valueOf(res));  

        JOptionPane.showInternalMessageDialog(this, somar.somarNumeros(num1,num2)); 
        //B_Somar.setText(String.valueOf());   
        //JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,s);  

    }                                       

    private void TF_Valor1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                         

    private void TF_Valor2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                         


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton B_Somar;
    private javax.swing.JTextField TF_Resultado;
    private javax.swing.JTextField TF_Valor1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField TF_Valor2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

O método [`showInternalMessageDialog`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInternalMessageDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object)), assim como a maioria dos métodos de `JOptionPane`, espera como um de seus parâmetros um [**container**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) parente, se for passado `null`, ele vai buscar o container principal da aplicação, no caso, um JFrame, mas este método em especial espera que o container seja um `JInternalFrame` ou `JDesktopPane`, por isso estoura o erro informado. Passando o `this` da forma que fiz, estou referenciado a própria classe `TesteJInternalFrame` como parente, dessa forma o `JOptionPane` funcionará normalmente, sem travar toda a janela da aplicação, apenas os frames internos.

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: @Jose.Lemo veja a edição que fiz, com uma segunda forma de adaptar o código sem o erro.